# Identify Identity Provider type in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am enabling social login (Google, Facebook, Twitter) in my java ee application and authenticate through Keycloak. So far I have been able to authenticate the application directly through Keycloak and I am capturing the AccessToken with the below methodology:

```
AccessToken accessToken = ((KeycloakPrincipal) httpRequest.getUserPrincipal()).getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
```

Can I use this access token to identify the Identity Provider(Google/Facebook/Twitter) through which the User has logged in? My basic requirement is to find out the Identity Provider through which the user has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

The access token contains field *iss*. That is an issuer - identifies principal that issued the JWT = used Identity Provider.

Comment: The issuer is showing the url where the keycloak server is hosted and not the identity provider